# Finding the path with the least number of edges under a certain ticket cost

Tags: constraints, path-finding

I’m having trouble with this local contest problem. We need to find the shortest number of "plays" for 3 players in [position1, position2, position3] to move to [dest1, dest2, dest3]. All players must move each play, none of them can be in the same place at once, and we are given an adjacency list with neighbours and mode of transportation. We also have a maximum number of tickets for each mode of transportation (There are 3 different modes of transportation, and they all cost 1 ticket per usage). Any ideas?

Only thing I've come up with so far is brute-force BFS with heuristic, since we are also given physical coordinates for each position, but this is way too slow.

Comment: can't you use a modified version of Dijkstra? Something like update the vertices weights every time a player moves and set the weight going to an occupied vertex to infinity so it is never chosen